# Async action not running Async React Redux Thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to build a React App that fetches data from 7 api's, on initial load, then stores all the data in Redux, to use within the app. I am pretty new to React and a bit of a coding noob.

I have a dispatch function on my first app page that fires on componentDidMount() and runs the fetchData() function in the action below.

```
export function getDataPending(actionType) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_" + actionType.toUpperCase() + "_PENDING"
  };
}

export function getDataSuccess(actionType, data) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_" + actionType.toUpperCase() + "_FULFILLED",
    payload: data
  };
}

export function getDataFailure(actionType, data) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_" + actionType.toUpperCase() + "_REJECTED",
    payload: data
  };
}
//Sub data fetches
export function fetchNicSalts() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getDataPending("nic_salt"));
    axios
      .get(
        "API_FEED"
      )
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(getDataSuccess("nic_salt", response));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(getDataFailure("nic_salt", err));
      });
  };
}

export function fetchFreebase() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getDataPending("freebase"));
    axios
      .get(
        "API_FEED"
      )
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(getDataSuccess("freebase", response));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(getDataFailure("freebase", err));
      });
  };
}
//Main data fetch
export function fetchData() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getDataPending("data"));
    dispatch(fetchFreebase());
    dispatch(fetchNicSalts());
    dispatch(getDataSuccess("data", null));
  };
}
```

There are only two api fetches at the moment, as I am trying to get them to run async.
Ideally what I want to happen the dispatches to run in this order.
FETCH_DATA_PENDING
FETCH_FREEBASE_PENDING
FETCH_FREEBASE_FULFILLED
FETCH_NIC_SALT_PENDING
FETCH_NIC_SALT_FULFILLED
**** next api *****
FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED

The data is being stored at the moment just in the wrong order. Please see image for current order.

[My data fulfillment order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mqNo.png)

As I say, I am self taught and not sure if I am on the right path, any advice is welcome. TIA.

Comment: Use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or async/await to synchronize your async code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your fetchFreebase and fetchNicSalts return the axios calls so that you can await them in the fetchData action.

This would look like this

```
export function getDataPending(actionType) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_" + actionType.toUpperCase() + "_PENDING"
  };
}

export function getDataSuccess(actionType, data) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_" + actionType.toUpperCase() + "_FULFILLED",
    payload: data
  };
}

export function getDataFailure(actionType, data) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_" + actionType.toUpperCase() + "_REJECTED",
    payload: data
  };
}
//Sub data fetches
export function fetchNicSalts() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getDataPending("nic_salt"));
    return axios
      .get(
        "API_FEED"
      )
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(getDataSuccess("nic_salt", response));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(getDataFailure("nic_salt", err));
      });
  };
}

export function fetchFreebase() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getDataPending("freebase"));
    return axios
      .get(
        "API_FEED"
      )
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(getDataSuccess("freebase", response));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(getDataFailure("freebase", err));
      });
  };
}
//Main data fetch
export function fetchData() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getDataPending("data"));
    await dispatch(fetchFreebase());
    await dispatch(fetchNicSalts());
    dispatch(getDataSuccess("data", null));
  };
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, that makes a lot of sense, thanks for showing me the adapted code too.